# Sequelize object.add not returning id?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize 3.27.0 with NodeJS 6.7.0 and Sqlite 3.

I have 'many to many' relationship and trying to create a new relationship, but on doing so I see no id returned. I have created a simple test case to try to understand what I could be doing wrong. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong:

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    }
});

var Project = sequelize.define('project', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    }
});

var UserProject = sequelize.define('user_project', {
  id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
  },
  role: Sequelize.STRING,
});

User.belongsToMany(Project, { through: UserProject });
Project.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserProject });

sequelize.sync({}).then(function () {
    var userX;

    User.create({}).then(function (user) {
        userX = user;
        return Project.create({});
    }).then(function (project) {
        return userX.addProject(project);
    }).then(function (userProject) {
        console.log(userProject.id);
    });
});
```

As you can see the id for UserProject does have 'autoIncrement' set to true. The result of running the above is 'undefined' for the value of id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I haven't found a concrete answer, the best one I have found is that the 'UserProject' table should be treated as a 'mapping table', so the the entries don't really need a distinct ID.

What this means is the table entries only have meaning when used in conjunction with the source or destination tables. It simply exists to define an association and therefore is worth noting when presented with "[is not associated to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077987/sequelize-many-to-many-failing-with-is-not-associated-to-when-trying-to-associ/42078804#42078804)" type errors.